# Create Dictionary of two numpy.ndarray?

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, dictionary

I have two numpy.ndarray

```
[[' THE OLD TESTAMENT ']
[' SEAN SONG ']
[' CITY WALK ']]
```

and

```
[[' This is the name of an Old Testament ']
 [' Hello this is great ']
[' Wait the way you are doing ']]
```

I want to convert these ndarray to dictionary.

```
 {
"THE OLD TESTAMENT": "This is the name of an Old Testament",
"SEAN SONG": "Hello this is great",
"CITY WALK": Wait the way you are doing 
 }
```

I am using the code written below

```
keys = df.as_matrix()
print (keys)
values = df1.as_matrix()
print (values)
new_dict = dict(izip(keys, values))
```

Comment: The real question is how did you end up with these horrible arrays?

Answer (score 2):

Converting to `arrays` is not necessary, use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select first column with `zip`:

```
new_dict = dict(zip(df.iloc[:, 0], df1.iloc[:, 0]))
```

Or select columns by names:

```
new_dict = dict(zip(df['col'], df1['col']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Squeeze your arrays first:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: keys = np.array(
   ...:     [[' THE OLD TESTAMENT '],
   ...:     [' SEAN SONG '],
   ...:     [' CITY WALK ']]
   ...: )

In [3]: values = np.array(
   ...:     [[' This is the name of an Old Testament '],
   ...:      [' Hello this is great '],
   ...:     [' Wait the way you are doing ']]
   ...: )

In [4]: dict(zip(keys.squeeze(), values.squeeze()))
Out[4]:
{' CITY WALK ': ' Wait the way you are doing ',
 ' SEAN SONG ': ' Hello this is great ',
 ' THE OLD TESTAMENT ': ' This is the name of an Old Testament '}
```

Or just use slicing:

```
In [5]: dict(zip(keys[:,0], values[:,0]))
Out[5]:
{' CITY WALK ': ' Wait the way you are doing ',
 ' SEAN SONG ': ' Hello this is great ',
 ' THE OLD TESTAMENT ': ' This is the name of an Old Testament '}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
keyh=[[' THE OLD TESTAMENT '],
[' SEAN SONG '],
[' CITY WALK ']]

valueh=[[' This is the name of an Old Testament '],
 [' Hello this is great '],
[' Wait the way you are doing ']]

dictionary = dict(zip([item[0] for item in keyh], [item[0] for item in valueh]))
```

**Output**

```
{
"THE OLD TESTAMENT": "This is the name of an Old Testament",
"SEAN SONG": "Hello this is great",
"CITY WALK": "Wait the way you are doing"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
keys = [[' THE OLD TESTAMENT '],[' SEAN SONG '],[' CITY WALK ']]

values = [[' This is the name of an Old Testament '], [' Hello this is great '],[' Wait the way you are doing ']]


keys = [x[0] for x in keys]

values = [x[0] for x in values]


dictionary = dict(zip(keys, values))
```